# Apache2 - enable directory listing not working

Tags: apache, apache2

> I have installed apache2 on SLES12-SP5 server. I need to enable directory listing to view all the directories from the browser url. I have updated the following entry in the /ect/apache2/httpd.conf file. After service restart, i am not able to see the directory list in the browser and i get Error - 404 . How to enable this directory listing?

```
<Directory "/scratch/log_dir">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted    
</Directory>
```

Comment: The path `/scratch/log_dir` looks a bit strange ... sure that you have a physical folder under the _absolute_ path `/scratch/log_dir` in your root file system? And sure that this folder is part of the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` configured for that http host?

Comment: The /scratch/log_dir is the relative path but not an absolute path. Should we need to configure only absolute path directories? If so, what entry i need to add it in the httpd.conf file. Could you please suggest as i am novice to this apache2 configuration.

Comment: Nope, `/scratch/log_dir` is an absolute path, `scratch/log_dir` would be a relative path. Take a look at the documentation of the `Directory` directive: 
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory

Comment: Thanks. I need to access the file contents located under /scrach/log_dir. what entry i need to add in the http.conf file. I tried with below entry but it didnt work for me. Could you please share with me a sample of it. Appreciate this help.

<Directory "/scratch/log_dir">
    Options +Indexes
</Directory>

Comment: I already asked about that above: do you _really_ have such a folder in your server side file system under the absolute path `/scrach/log_dir`? That is possible, but would be highly unconventional. That is the path you configured. If that folder exists the configuration works. If it does not exist, then the condiguration has no effect.

Comment: Yes, the folder does exists. But it didnt work when i defined that in the httpd.conf. Are there anything that i am missing there?

Comment: Did you really understand what I asked? So I ask the other way around: _where_ does that folder exist?

Comment: i got your question. The location does exist under parent directory - /scratch/log_dir

Comment: Why is it so hard to make a clear statement? What is "parent directory" now?
What I want to clearly tell apart is whether that folder is located in the file system's root (as the _absolute_ path notation suggests) or if it is located under the http server's host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder (which is what I suspect and what would explain the issue).

Comment: Yes, its part of file system's root but not part of DOCUMENT_ROOT.

Comment: OK, thanks, so now we finally know part of the actual situation. What I fail to understand that is why you insist that `/scratch/log_dir` should be a relative path (see your first comment here). That is simply wrong in two ways in my eyes. Could you please add some more information to your question: 1. the actual URL you request from the browser that leads to the 404 and 2. the entries you get in the http server's error log file when making such a request. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out in understanding the issue. Sorry if my queries are unclear. The reason for using the relative path - /scratch/log_dir is - we are running ansible playbook and its logs are getting stored in this location. We are giving the access to endusers via browser to access all the logs.

Comment: 1. actual url tried from browser - http://vmansible02/scratch/log_dir/       
2. error_log --->      [Wed Oct 19 02:29:45.771800 2022] [autoindex:error] [pid 6805] [client 10.000.004.01:62116] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /srv/www/htdocs/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.html.var) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

/etc/apache2/httpd.conf entry:
<Directory "/scratch/log_dir">
    Options +Indexes
</Directory>

Comment: Once more: `/scratch/log_dir` is an _absolute_ path _per definition_ ... What do you actually mean when you insist that this should be a _relative_ path? What does the term "relative path" describe in your eyes?

Comment: That last error log entry clearly contradicts what you posted above as the configuration you are using.

Comment: To get past the issue, i will remove the /scratch/log_dir path from the httpd.conf and replace that with the new folder created under DOCUMENT_ROOT and retry the steps.  Hope that way it should work.

Comment: Currently i see DocumentRoot is set to /srv/www/htdocs path. If i want to change this path to different dir location. What entry i need to add in what .conf file? could you please share that info.

Comment: That is the directive `DocumentRoot` in the configuration of the (virtual) http host.